# Incrementally dump data to JSON File in a For Loop

Tags: python, json, memory

I have a Python script that pulls all records from a SQL table, transforms it and dumps it to a JSON file. It looks something like this.

```
data = []

# accumulate data into one large list
for record in get_sql_data():
    obj = MyObject(record)
    transformed_obj = transform(obj)
    data.append(transformed_obj)

# dump all data at once to json file
with open("result.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump({
        "name": "My data",
        "timestamp": datetime.datetime.now(),
        "data": data,
    }, f)
```

This used to work fine when my SQL table was small. Now it has millions of records and the script crashes because it runs out of memory when adding objects to the `data` list.

Is there anyway to incrementally dump these objects to the file so I don't need to create this massive `data` list? Something like this:

```
with open("result.json", "w") as f:
    for record in get_sql_data():
        obj = MyObject(record)
        transformed_obj = transform(obj)
        # write transformed_obj to json file
```

Note, the object transformation step is very complex so I can't do that step in the database. I need to do it in Python.

Comment: Could look into using the JSONL format instead for dumping millions of records incrementally?

Comment: @IainShelvington dumping to a JSONL file works perfectly. Thanks!